# Re-notify user of account in Drupal

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-6

When a user signs up at a Drupal site, there is a configurable message that Drupal will send the user letting them know their username and password.

I have about 1,000 users that I imported, but at the time, I didn't want to notify them - but now I do. Is there a way notify the users without reimporting them?

I looked through some of the modules I thought might contain that function, but I couldn't find it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is a way: If you want to do this just one time, I recommend using a quick n' easy way... `drupal_bootstrap()`. In an external php file call this function to bootstrap Drupal, then load users and dispatch email messages. Here's a pseudo-code:

```
<?php
// ...

// Change directory to Drupal root
chdir(../../); 

// Bootstrap Drupal
require './includes/bootstrap.inc';

// You might want to pass DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE instead
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$db_result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {users}');

while ($user_object = db_fetch_object($db_result)) {
    // TODO: Use drupal_mail() to send desired emails

    // User Name: $user_object->name
    // User Email: $user_object->email

    // Don't forget to pass 'em through the check_plain()
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Read more at Drupal API: [`drupal_mail()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_mail) [`drupal_bootstrap()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_bootstrap/6).

Comment: Just curious, will this allow you to email the user his/her password (as the question asked)?

Comment: Using this we can send users a new password, not the stored one ofcourse.  
Also we can make a automatic login url containing a hash, letting users to reset their passwords as drupal does by default.